# Unable to get result from two sets because of `Unable to cast object of type to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter``

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, dbcontext

I'm pursuing a way to get result from 2 sets in .NET using Entity framework. From what I've seen on the internet, most of the approaches are similar to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1072284/Return-Multiple-Result-Set-using-Entity-Framework) one right here. I did the same thing but I get the error

> Unable to cast object of type Domain.Models.AppContext to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'

Now the code that I use is pretty straight-forward. This is my `AppContext`.

```
public partial class AppContext: DbContext {
    public AppContext() {}

    public AppContext(DbContextOptions < AppContext > options): base(options) {
      Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet < Class1 > Class1 {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public virtual DbSet < Class2 > Class2 {
      get;
      set;
    }
```

After that, I go to my class where the function is located and do `public ParametarRepository(AppContext context) : base(context)` where `base(context)` is

```
public class Repository < T >: IRepository < T > where T: BaseEntity {
    protected AppContext _context;
    private DbSet < T > entities;
    public Repository(AppContext context) {
      _context = context;
      entities = _context.Set < T > ();
    }
}
```

When I execute the code from the example in the link, namely

```
public MultiResultDomain GetMultipleResultSetFromSP() {
  MultiResultDomain domainEntity = new MultiResultDomain();
  var connection = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
  var command = connection.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = "dbo.TestResultSets";
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  try {
    connection.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    List < Class1 > links = ((IObjectContextAdapter) _context).ObjectContext.Translate < Class1 > (reader).ToList();
    reader.NextResult();
    List < Class2 > data = ((IObjectContextAdapter) _context).ObjectContext.Translate < Class2 > (reader).ToList();

    domainEntity.Links = links;
    domainEntity.Data = data;

    return domainEntity;
  } finally {
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

I get the error that I mentioned earlier. Interesting thing is that if I debug this and check the value of `reader`, it does have values for `Class 1` and after `NextResult()`, it has the values for `Class 2` as well but sadly I can't access them as the code fails in the part where I should cast them to an object. EF version I have is `3.1.3` and .NET 3.1 version

Comment: Please use a version tag indicating which EF version you're using. It's probably some EF core version and `IObjectContextAdapter` doesn't exist there.

Comment: Just updated it and added 3.1.3 as EF version

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to do, but using stored procedures when you have a full-fledged ORM is considered a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in EF Core, the tracking issue is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127).

You can interop with ADO.NET directly, or with Dapper which will handle multiple results and materialize the objects for you.  See: [QueryMultiple](https://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple).